# Join a dataframe with multiple dataframes stored in a list with different column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, purrr

I have a dataframe (`df1`) and a list of dataframes (`test`) like below; I want to join `df1` with each of the datafraems in `test` and populate a new column (`X`), while keeping all the other records intact.

```
read.table(text = "Fruits      A    B     C     D
                   Apple       10   1.3   NA    NA
                   Orange      0.2  NA    0.21  NA
                   Grape       NA   0.06  51    0.7
                   Grape       NA   0.06  51    0.7
                   Grape       1    0.06  51    0.7
                   Grape       NA   0.06  NA    0.8
                   Berry       11   20    0.3   0.04
                   Apple       NA   1.1   0.5   NA   
                   Apple       NA   1.2   0.5   NA
                   Apple       NA   1.3   0.1   NA
                   Berry       NA   NA    0.3   0.04
                   Berry       1    NA    0.9   0.01
                   Apple       1    1.3   0.5   NA
                   Apple       1    1.3   0.5   NA", 
            stringsAsFactors = FALSE, header = TRUE) -> df1

list(data.frame(Fruits = c("Apple"), A = 10, X = "oh"),
     data.frame(Fruits = c("Berry"), A = 11, B = 20, X = "duh")) -> test
```

Here's the expected output:

```
   Fruits    A     B     C    D    X
1   Apple 10.0  1.30    NA   NA   oh
2  Orange  0.2    NA  0.21   NA   NA   
3   Grape   NA  0.06 51.00 0.70   NA
4   Grape   NA  0.06 51.00 0.70   NA
5   Grape  1.0  0.06 51.00 0.70   NA
6   Grape   NA  0.06    NA 0.80   NA
7   Berry 11.0 20.00  0.30 0.04   duh
8   Apple   NA  1.10  0.50   NA   NA
9   Apple   NA  1.20  0.50   NA   NA
10  Apple   NA  1.30  0.10   NA   NA
11  Berry   NA    NA  0.30 0.04   NA
12  Berry  1.0    NA  0.90 0.01   NA
13  Apple  1.0  1.30  0.50   NA   NA
14  Apple  1.0  1.30  0.50   NA   NA
```

Simply looping through the dataframes within `test` does not work since it creates a dataframe for each `..._join` and also creates duplicated rows for the second iteration. Maybe we can use a conditional `mutate`.

```
purrr::map(test, ~full_join(df1, .x))
```

It is more than likely I am missing something simple, but I don't want to join the outputs of `full_join` afterwards since my actual `df1` has over 1M rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `purrr::reduce()` instead of `map()`. But this raises the issue that after the first iteration, `X` appears in both dataframes and is treated as a key. One workaround would be to give all the `X` columns unique names, then coalesce after joining.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

test2 <- imap(test, ~ rename(.x, "X{.y}" := X))

test2 %>% 
  reduce(full_join, .init = df1) %>% 
  mutate(X = coalesce(X1, X2), .keep = "unused")
```

```
   Fruits    A     B     C    D    X
1   Apple 10.0  1.30    NA   NA   oh
2  Orange  0.2    NA  0.21   NA <NA>
3   Grape   NA  0.06 51.00 0.70 <NA>
4   Grape   NA  0.06 51.00 0.70 <NA>
5   Grape  1.0  0.06 51.00 0.70 <NA>
6   Grape   NA  0.06    NA 0.80 <NA>
7   Berry 11.0 20.00  0.30 0.04  duh
8   Apple   NA  1.10  0.50   NA <NA>
9   Apple   NA  1.20  0.50   NA <NA>
10  Apple   NA  1.30  0.10   NA <NA>
11  Berry   NA    NA  0.30 0.04 <NA>
12  Berry  1.0    NA  0.90 0.01 <NA>
13  Apple  1.0  1.30  0.50   NA <NA>
14  Apple  1.0  1.30  0.50   NA <NA>
```

If `test` has a lot of elements, it'll be annoying to list out `coalesce(X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn)`. In that case, you can use this alternative:

```
test2 %>% 
  reduce(full_join, .init = df1) %>% 
  mutate(X = coalesce(!!!syms(paste0("X", seq_along(test2)))), .keep = "unused")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
library(powerjoin)
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
   reduce(power_full_join, .init = df1, conflict = coalesce_xy)
```

---

Or as @moodymudskipper mentioned in the comments, `power_full_join` does join recursively

```
power_full_join(df1, test, conflict = coalesce_xy)
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems like this may be a good use of the new `rows_update()` method. You can iterate over the list of rows to update inside a `reduce` to apply them sequentially. For example

```
purrr::reduce(test, function(data, match) {
  rows_update(data, match, setdiff(names(match), "X"))
}, .init=data.frame(df1, X=NA_character_))
```

This adds a column named X which is all NA at first, and then at each iteration it updates the value of X using whatever overlapping columns there are that are not named "X".

Comment: ```Error in `rows_check_key_df()`:
! `x` key values are not unique.```

Comment: @M-- Did you get that error with the sample data provided? It worked for me. Tested with `dplyr_1.1.0`

Comment: Nah, it works for the sample since there are only one row per each match. I already upvoted your answer, but I went with the other answer since it provides a solution for more complicated cases. Thank you.